# How check condition of checkbox when uncheck/check with id of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm using css and javascript to check condition of value of partner Code is null and 01

1. If user checks checkbox is PARTNER, value of partnerName '01 - Elite' and value of partnerCode is '01' will send when submit
2. If user unchecks checkbox is PARTNER, value of partnerName is 'NULL' and value of partnerCode is 'NULL' will send when submit

This is my code:

```html
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Partner</th>
    <td colspan="0" style="margin-top: 4px;">
        <input id="parnerNameCheck" name="parnerNameCheck" type="checkbox"/><span>PARTNER</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="partnerName" name="partnerName" disabled>
            <option value="" selected>Choose One</option>
            <option>01 - Elite</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="partnerCode" name="partnerCode" type="hidden" value="01" />
    </td>
</tr>           
    
<script>
  $('#parnerNameCheck').click(function() {
    console.log('parnerNameCheck  checked:' + $("#parnerNameCheck").is(":checked"));
    $('#partnerName').prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked"));
    $('#partnerCode').prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked"));       
  });
</script>
```

**UPDATED**:

```js
$('#parnerNameCheck').click(function() {
    console.log('parnerNameCheck  checked:' + $("#parnerNameCheck").is(":checked"));
    $('#partnerName').prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked"));
    $('#partnerCode').prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked")); 
    $("#partnerCode").val('');
});
```

But when I uncheck checkbox is PARTNER, value of partnerCode is 01 still sending when submit.
So how to fix the problem? thank a lot

Comment: I do not think ajax is a relevant tag here. replace it with jquery

Answer (score 0):

set `$("#partnerCode").val('');`

```js
  $('#parnerNameCheck').click(function() {
              console.log('parnerNameCheck  checked:' + $("#parnerNameCheck").is(":checked"));
              $('#partnerName').prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked"));
              $('#partnerCode').prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked")); 
               $("#partnerCode").val('');
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
          <th scope="row">Partner</th>
          <td colspan="0" style="margin-top: 4px;">
                 <input id="parnerNameCheck" name="parnerNameCheck" type="checkbox"/><span>PARTNER</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="partnerName" name="partnerName" disabled>
                    <option value="" selected>Choose One</option>
                    <option>01 - Elite</option>
                 </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="partnerCode" name="partnerCode" type="hidden" value="01" />
            </td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: I have tested as your suggestion, but it same problem

Comment: with your code, if checked PARTNER result is partnerName is '01 - Elite' and partnerCode is NULL, and if unchecked PARTNER result is partnerName is NULL, and partnerCode = 01. So it cannot get current value as expected

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the ability to toggle the value of partnerCode. Your updated code would only set the value of parnetCode to null and that's it.

Below is the code that would switch the values for partnerCode:

```
$('#parnerNameCheck').click(function() {
  console.log('parnerNameCheck: ' + $("#partnerCode").val());
  $('#partnerName').prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked"));
  $('#partnerCode').prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked")); 
  
  // Declare variables 
  var partnerCode = $("#partnerCode");
  var partnerCodeVal = partnerCode.val();
  
  // Apply condition to $("#partnerCode").val() 
  // that will switch between values
  partnerCode.val(partnerCodeVal === "01" ? "" : "01");
});
```

Working example - https://jsfiddle.net/ma4orbnw/1/